# UISplitViewController like mail app

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to make my application similar to mail.app in vertical orientation. It should show a master view controller by button, but not in pop over and in horizontal orientation it should look like a simple UiSplitViewController.

Have you any ideas? Is there any usable open source projects which could be re-used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail.app is using a standard `UISplitViewController`. The behaviour was changed in iOS 5 so that it no longer uses a popover, but instead slides in the master view controller from the left. Although technically I guess you can still call that a "popover".

This may be confusing because the documentation and delegate methods still refer to a popover controller, but if you create a blank split view project from Xcode and run it on an iOS 5 device or simulator, you will get the new behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) - very useful alternative to the `UISplitViewController`, has some nice configuration options.